# Dealing with an unmotivated supervisor

Tags: management, new-job, internship

I'm an IT intern in a small company (part of a large network of card designing and printing companies). As I'm very new in the company, I'm excited to learn about our production process and how it could be improved (which is the main task of IT here), but my supervisor is unmotivated to do stuff, and since he delegates tasks to me, this affects me as well.

Our IT department is just me and my supervisor (a more senior IT guy left a week after I joined), and I keep hearing things like "Hey, don't bother with this little detail" or "My salary is too low for this, so don't make it".

What can I do?

Comment: What were you hired for?

Comment: What is it you are wanting?  More tasks? A different supervisor? To quit and become a professional Line dancer?  Questions asking for a generic what should I do are too open ended for great answers and have been declared off topic. [help]

Comment: Is it a job that you would like to take on permanently when your education is complete? Imagine your team (supervisor + intern) does a recognisable excellent job, due to your hard work. And when you leave, it's performance drops (due to the lazy bum who supervised you). There's a chance that you would come back, become the supervisor or the whole team, and when you get an intern, treat them better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***Unfortunately, not much.***

You're just the intern. You're there for just about long enough for people to learn your name before you're gone again.

Having worked three co-ops (read internships), I can tell you that you won't have the experience, reputation, or political savvy to change whatever may be wrong with company you're working for.

If someone there needs to write a final review for you just make sure you stay in their good graces.

Comment: +1 for 'You're just the intern. You're there for just about long enough for people to learn your name before you're gone again.' Aced it

Comment: ... Perhaps to learn how many sugars each person has in there tea

Answer (score 1):

You are an intern. Usually what happens before you arrive is that the company figures out a small project and a mentor. Your boss has probably lost your mentor and is trying to figure out an alternative. Possibly with the project.

These projects is usually something that is "would be nice if we had the time".

I would suggest give it a few weeks and it nothing materializes ask what small project you can do.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is take the supervisor's duties off his plate.  Since he is unmotivated and you seem very motivated, talk him into taking his normal tasks and moving them to you.  If all works out well he does nothing (win for him), you do his job (win for you), and he just has to help out with questions.  I would start slow on this.  He will either act guarded and resist or just shovel everything on you as soon as he can.

Answer (score 0):

Take everything he gives you.  You are building your resume, and it will make you VERY marketable for your next job.  See the value in what is happening.

Think of what you will be able to say on your interview for your next job.

"Well, I was brought in to XYZ company as an intern, and I quickly took on more and more responsibilities.  When a person more senior than I left the company, my supervisor expanded my role and I was able to quickly take on more responsibility"

You have a wonderful opportunity to learn and become a seasoned worker.  Take FULL advantage of it, do not complain, and keep your resume updated so that you can apply for a full position at your company, or move on to someone who will appreciate all the responsibilities you have taken on.